# How to add objects into an array without repeating value of one of the properties of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, indexof

I am trying to insert data into an array. The data is of object form with 2 properties name and value. I am retrieving the data from a different array object with a completely different structure.

The new array that I am creating is as follow:

```
newarray = [Object, Object, Object]
```

where `Object = {name: "abc", value: "12"}`

This is what I am doing for my purpose:

```
var newarray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < oldarray.length; i++) {
    a = newarray.indexOf(oldarray[i].studentname);
    if (a == -1) {
        newarray.push({
            name: oldarray[i].studentname,
            value: oldarray[i].marks
        })
    }
}
```

I don't want the student name to repeat so I have tried to use indexOf to check the occurrence of the name in the array. But I am not doing it correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's clear that English isn't your native language (which is *absolutely fine*, perfect English is **not** required), so I'll mention: Saying "please rectify" at the end of a question will come across as quite rude to the majority of English readers. (Even the "please check" that's common and perfectly find in the dialect of the Indian subcontinent reads as rude to Americans.)

Comment: What does "not doing it correctly" mean? Say *what* is wrong. Ideally, show an example array, the output you want, and the output you're getting instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newarray= [];
for(var i=0; i<oldarray.length; i++)
{
    var found = false;
    for (var j=0; j<newarray.length; j++) {
      if (oldarray[i].studentname == newarray[j].studentname) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        newarray.push({
            name : oldarray[i].studentname,
            value :oldarray[i].marks
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
a = newarray.indexOf(oldarray[i].studentname);
if (a == -1)
```

looks to see if the student's **name** is an entry in the array. But the entries you're putting in the array aren't just namnes, they're objects.

If you want to find if an object with the same name is in the array, you can use `Array#some`:

```
if (!newarray.some(function(entry) { return entry.name == oldarray[i].studentname; })) {
    // It's not there, add it
}
```

`Array#some` calls its callback for each entry. If the callback returns a truthy value for any entry, `some` stops and returns `true`; if the callback never returns a truthy value (or the array is empty), `some` returns `false`.

It's a bit more concise with ES2015, if you're using ES2015:

```
if (!newarray.some(entry => entry.name == oldarray[i].studentname)) {
    // It's not there, add it
}
```

---

`==` will require that the names be in the same capitalization, of course. If that may not be true, you might want to make both sides lower (or upper) case first.

---

I don't see `a` declared anywhere, make sure you're not falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Answer (score -1):

```js
var newarray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < oldarray.length; i++) {
  a = findWithAttr(newarray, "studentname", oldarray[i].studentname);
  if (a == undefined) {
    newarray.push({
      name: oldarray[i].studentname,
      value: oldarray[i].marks
    })
  }
}

function findWithAttr(array, attr, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (array[i][attr] === value) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```